# Magento Extension 404 page not found error

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.9.2.2

I am trying to use an exiting extension.Extension is showing fine in advance tab also in menu and system configuration pages showing but when i am trying to visit the extension data grid page it redirect me to frontend with 404 not found error.

[image]

You can view the extension hierarchy

adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <reward translate="title" module="reward">
                    <title>Reward Points</title>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <balance translate="title">
                            <title>Manage Balances</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </balance>
                        <affect translate="title">
                            <title>Can Spend Reward Points when Creating Orders</title>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                        </affect>
                    </children>
                </reward>
                <customer>
                    <children>
                        <rates translate="title">
                            <title>Reward Exchange Rates</title>
                            <sort_order>80</sort_order>
                        </rates>
                    </children>
                </customer>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <reward translate="title" module="reward">
                                    <title>Reward Points</title>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                </reward>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
 <menu>
    <customer>
        <children>
            <reward translate="title" module="reward">
                <title>Reward Exchange Rates</title>
                <action>adminhtml/reward_rate</action>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <depends>
                    <module>Reward</module>
                    <config>reward/general/is_enabled</config>
                </depends>
                <resource>customer/rates</resource>
            </reward>
        </children>
    </customer>
</menu>
```

Config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Reward>
        <version>1.7.0.0.15</version>
    </Reward>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <reward>
            <class>Reward_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>reward_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </reward>
        <reward_mysql4>
            <class>Reward_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <reward>
                    <table>reward</table>
                </reward>
                <reward_history>
                    <table>reward_history</table>
                </reward_history>
                <reward_rate>
                    <table>reward_rate</table>
                </reward_rate>
                <reward_salesrule>
                    <table>reward_salesrule</table>
                </reward_salesrule>
            </entities>
        </reward_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <reward_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Reward</module>
                <class>Reward_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </reward_setup>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <reward>
            <class>Reward_Block</class>
        </reward>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <reward>
            <class>Reward_Helper</class>
        </reward>
    </helpers>
    <template>
        <email>
            <reward_notification_balance_update_template translate="label" module="reward">
                <label>Reward Points Balance Update</label>
                <file>reward_balance_update.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </reward_notification_balance_update_template>
            <reward_notification_expiry_warning_template translate="label" module="reward">
                <label>Reward Points Expiry Warning</label>
                <file>reward_expiry_warning.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </reward_notification_expiry_warning_template>
        </email>
    </template>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/total_quote_reward</class>
                    <after>wee,discount,tax,tax_subtotal,grand_total</after>
                    <before>giftcardaccount,customerbalance</before>
                    <renderer>reward/checkout_total</renderer>
                </reward>
            </totals>
        </quote>
        <order_invoice>
            <totals>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/total_invoice_reward</class>
                </reward>
            </totals>
        </order_invoice>
        <order_creditmemo>
            <totals>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/total_creditmemo_reward</class>
                </reward>
            </totals>
        </order_creditmemo>
    </sales>
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote_address>
            <reward_points_balance><to_order>*</to_order></reward_points_balance>
            <reward_currency_amount><to_order>*</to_order></reward_currency_amount>
            <base_reward_currency_amount><to_order>*</to_order></base_reward_currency_amount>
        </sales_convert_quote_address>
    </fieldsets>
    <events>
        <newsletter_subscriber_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>customerSubscribed</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </newsletter_subscriber_save_commit_after>
        <paypal_prepare_line_items>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>addPaypalRewardItem</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </paypal_prepare_line_items>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>orderCompleted</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
        <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>quoteCollectTotalsBefore</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
        <sales_quote_merge_after>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>quoteMergeAfter</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_merge_after>
        <sales_order_load_after>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>orderLoadAfter</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_load_after>
        <sales_order_invoice_register>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>invoiceRegister</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_invoice_register>
        <sales_order_invoice_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>applyRewardSalesrulePoints</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_invoice_save_commit_after>
        <sales_order_creditmemo_refund>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>creditmemoRefund</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_creditmemo_refund>
        <sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>creditmemoSaveAfter</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
        <sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>processOrderPlace</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </sales_model_service_quote_submit_before>
        <sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>revertRewardPoints</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure>
        <checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>processOrderPlace</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single>
        <checkout_multishipping_refund_all>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>revertRewardPointsForAllOrders</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </checkout_multishipping_refund_all>
    </events>
    <pdf>
        <totals>
            <reward translate="title">
                <title>Reward Points</title>
                <source_field>reward_currency_amount</source_field>
                <font_size>7</font_size>
                <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                <sort_order>650</sort_order>
                <amount_prefix>-</amount_prefix>
            </reward>
        </totals>
    </pdf>
</global>



<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <reward>
                <file>reward.xml</file>
            </reward>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Reward>
                <files>
                    <default>Reward.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Reward>
        </modules>
    </translate>
    <routers>
        <reward>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Reward</module>
                <frontName>reward</frontName>
            </args>
        </reward>
    </routers>
    <events>
        <customer_session_init>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>checkRates</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </customer_session_init>
        <customer_save_after>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>customerRegister</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_after>
        <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>preparePaymentMethod</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
        <sales_quote_payment_import_data_before>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>paymentDataImport</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_payment_import_data_before>
        <invitation_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <reward>
                    <class>reward/observer</class>
                    <method>invitationToCustomer</method>
                </reward>
            </observers>
        </invitation_save_commit_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
<default>
    <reward>
        <general>
            <is_enabled>1</is_enabled>
            <is_enabled_on_front>1</is_enabled_on_front>
            <publish_history>1</publish_history>
            <expiry_calculation>static</expiry_calculation>
            <landing_page>reward-points</landing_page>
        </general>
        <notification>
            <email_sender>general</email_sender>
            <subscribe_by_default>1</subscribe_by_default>
            <balance_update_template>reward_notification_balance_update_template</balance_update_template>
            <expiry_warning_template>reward_notification_expiry_warning_template</expiry_warning_template>
        </notification>
    </reward>
    <sales>
        <totals_sort>
            <reward>80</reward>
        </totals_sort>
    </sales>
</default>
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <reward_balance_warning_notification>
            <schedule><cron_expr>1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>reward/observer::scheduledBalanceExpireNotification</model></run>
        </reward_balance_warning_notification>
        <reward_expire_points>
            <schedule><cron_expr>1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>reward/observer::scheduledPointsExpiration</model></run>
        </reward_expire_points>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

url i am using to access

http://127.0.0.1:8080/dev2/index.php/admin/reward_rate/index/key/b709....

what is wrong with this

Comment: You don't have an `adminhtml` router defined in your config.xml, only frontend

Comment: Have you just upgraded to 1.9.2.2 from a previous version?

Comment: Can you please send me the route for the admin.we were using magento enterprise 1.10 and now move to community 1.9.2.2 and i am trying to use enterprise reward point extension

Answer (score 0):

**Enabled** "Admin routing compatibility mode for extensions" from admin panel 
    Under Menu "System => Configuration", 
    Under Tab "Advanced"
    Under Section "Admin"
    Under Group "Security"

**OR**

```html
&lt;admin&gt;
  &lt;routers&gt;
    &lt;adminhtml&gt; &lt;!-- Mage_Adminhtml route name as per SUPEE-6788 --&gt;
      &lt;args&gt;
        &lt;modules&gt;
          &lt;reward after="Mage_Adminhtml"&gt;Reward&lt;/reward&gt;
  &lt;/modules&gt;
   &lt;/args&gt;
 &lt;/adminhtml&gt;
  &lt;/routers&gt;
&lt;/admin&gt;
```

And place your controllers under "Reward/controllers/Adminhtml" folder.

Then url would be http://127.0.0.1:8080/dev2/index.php/admin/adminhtml_rate/index/key/b709...

Comment: Security setup under advance->admin is already enable.I put your routing and move the controller under adminhtml.Clear cache but still same result.

Comment: please check this link how i can define routes to get it work 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4KrE.png